# How to access to the text that is in a section that exists more than once in a html file?

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyvKW.png)

How do I do to access to the value of the budget, just '6000000'.

```
tent1 = filmclean.find('h3',{'class':'subheading'}).get_text()
```

I know that this only returns 'Box Office', but if I do:

```
tent1 = filmclean.find('div',{'class':'txt-block'}).get_text()
```

it returns "Taglines: An offer you can't refuse." which, I belive, is the text for the first time that the class 'subheading' it appears.

Comment: Please share the URL

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the markup on picture, you can do:

```
print( filmclean.select_one('h3.subheading + div h4').find_next(text=True).strip() )
```

But without URL is hard to be 100% sure.